# Why can't I create a MySQL stored procedure in PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, stored-procedures

I tried to create a stored prucedure with the following code:

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE AddTrickBaseInvert(
    IN invertName       VARCHAR(16),
    IN invertType       TINYINT(1)
)
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO trick_bases (type)
    VALUES (1);
    INSERT INTO trick_bases_invert (
        baseId,
        name,
        type
    )
    VALUES (
        LAST_INSERT_ID(),
        name,
        type
    );
END //
DELIMITER ;
```

It worked when I tried to run a MySQL test on localhost/phpmyadmin/, but when I tried to create the same procedure using the identically same SQL code via PHP, it gave me the following error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'DELIMITER $$ CREATE PROCEDURE AddTrickBaseInvert( IN invertName ' at line 1 ...

The PHP code is here:

```
$sql = '
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE AddTrickBaseInvert(
    IN invertName       VARCHAR(16),
    IN invertType       TINYINT(1)
)
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO trick_bases (type)
    VALUES (1);
    INSERT INTO trick_bases_invert (
        baseId,
        name,
        type
    )
    VALUES (
        LAST_INSERT_ID(),
        name,
        type
    );
END //
DELIMITER ;';
$oDb->exec($sql);
```

As you see, the SQL code is exactly the same, but somehow the procedure does not get created. I tried to do researches but I could not find any answers yet. Do I miss something essential from the codes above which is somehow included when I run the code in the SQL tab on localhost/phpmyadmin?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Dont use redefining Delimiter syntax, when using application code / command line of mysql. We redefine delimiter, to stop PHPMyadmin from parsing `;` as execution trigger

Comment: Thank you for your comment! Since I am pretty new to using and creating stored procedures, I am not quite sure what I should do differently in my case. Could you please explain it in more details? @MadhurBhaiya

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- You don't need to redefine Delimiter, when trying to Create a stored procedure using application code.
- Also, to avoid exceptions in certain cases, call `DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS` before the Create procedure statement.

Do the following instead:

```
// drop if procedure exists already or not
$sql_drop = 'DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS AddTrickBaseInvert';
$oDb->exec($sql_drop);

// Now call create procedure statement
$sql = '
CREATE PROCEDURE AddTrickBaseInvert(
    IN invertName       VARCHAR(16),
    IN invertType       TINYINT(1)
)
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO trick_bases (type)
    VALUES (1);
    INSERT INTO trick_bases_invert (
        baseId,
        name,
        type
    )
    VALUES (
        LAST_INSERT_ID(),
        name,
        type
    );
END';
$oDb->exec($sql);
```

Comment: @janika23 Happy to help :) Please check the updated answer now. I have added one more explanation, which will help you

Comment: That was actually the next thing my system started to complain about and I started to make new researches about! So double thanks!